# Which URL to use in request.post in python if form doesnt have an "action" attribute?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been following a book called "Web Scraping with Python". In the book and several guides I have read to use request.post to login to a website you need to access the backend that handles logins.

I have tried

```
import requests
params = {'email':'<email>', 'password':'<password>'}
r = requests.post('https://b2b.cellbes.fi/login', data=params)
```

for: https://b2b.cellbes.fi/login

In every guide I have seen everyone gets the post-url from the action attribute, but the site's form doesn't have that and the button also doesn't have anything.

I'm really not that good with web development but I had to do this for work. I really need this to work and I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I'm guessing the site uses Javascript to handle the login. You need to figure out what exactly it does, and do the same things from Python. Probably it's doing some sort of JSON websocket stuff so the server can say "too many login attempts" or whatever without reloading the page. The answer you already got tries to tell you this, but probably needs a few more iterations before you can properly understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the requests and responses from the action of logging in. This is called reverse engineering the HTTP requests. You want to see where the information to login gets posted.

See images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhw4X.jpg)

To do this, you have to inspect the website. Within chrome, you right click the page and click inspect. Clicking network tab takes you to the page where you can view all requests and responses the browser makes when pages are loaded. When you try logging in. You are presented with requests. I've highlighted the request in the image. You can see it's an HTTP Post request and if you scroll down on the right hand side you'll see a payload. That is your login information that's getting posted to the server. The request url is where you send to parameters. Hence

### Code Example

```
import requests
params = {'email':'<email>', 'password':'<password>'}
r = requests.post('https://storeapi.jetshop.se/', data=params)
```

### Additional Information

This type of inspect is one of the first things you should be doing when it comes to web scraping. You want to see what the website does to login. A login procedure is essentially a POST HTTP request and a GET HTTP request from the server. You are posting information to the server, which authenicates you and directs you towards the logged in part of the site.

HTTP Requests require headers, sometimes parameters, cookies to ensure that the request is genuine. You will find on some websites that the data you want is actually from making POST requests to a server and the response back is the data in a nice structured format called JSON data. This type of reverse engineering, where you look for the correct headers, any parameters and cookies and do a request to that specific URL you will be able to get data that you may not have known was there.

This type of mimicking the request is one of the most efficient ways to grab data where page has javascript on it. Web scraping pages that heavily rely on javascript can be challenging, particularly if your data needs are heavy. Hence why if you can get the data in a nice neat format it's always worth checking the website to see how the data appears on the page by looking around the requests and responses of the website. So my advice would be to always think about this for the sites you're wanting to scrape. Look at the HTML and look at the requests and responses before doing any coding first.

Comment: I tried the code example but it didn't seem to anything for me. I made a session, used session.post with the params, but session.get(...) to a URL that required login still redirected me to the login page

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
params = {'email':'<email>', 'password':'<password>'}
r = session.post('https://storeapi.jetshop.se/', params)
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
r = session.get('https://b2b.cellbes.fi/miehet/paita-vaaleansininen')
```

printing cookies didnt print any. The cellbes URL redirects to login page